# How do I migrate source code from one TFS server to another?

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS 2005 (I think) were we host some code in one domain. Now we would like the customer do host the code by itself and they have bought a new version of TFS 2010. How do I migrate the code from the old server to the new one. We don't care about history at this point since we will have the old system running for at least one year if something critical happen.

What I have done so far is the following:

1. Create a master branch in the new version and copied the old version to the new version with no problem.
2. Created a development branch from the master branch.
3. Now I would like to migrate the development code from the old tfs to the new tfs and this seems complicated.

I first thought it would  be as simple as checking out the whole development branch in the new TFS, delete all the files and just paste in the files from the old development branch. But that is not the case.

Maybe there are a simple tool I could use instead?

Comment: Btw, the first version of TFS is 2005! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps in the new server:

1. Create the Master Branch, check-in.
2. Copy the sources from the old server in the local workspace of the new server at the Master Branch location
3. Check-in to commit the sources to the new server.
4. Create the Dev branch from the Master Branch using the latest changeset of the Master branch. This will replicate the whole structure of the Master branch to the Dev one.
5. Exit Visual Studio
6. Using the Windows Explorer, delete all the content of the Dev branch in the local workspace of your new server.
7. Copy the sources from the old server of the Dev branch in the local workspace of the new server at the Dev branch location.
8. Use the **TFPT.EXE ONLINE** command of the Team Foundation Power Tools to simulate an offline/online switch that will create the pending changes of the new content of your Dev branch (the files you copied from the old server). Be careful you have everything the way you want it to be in TFS. The command is something like `tfpt.exe online /adds /deletes /modify /recurse .` (check the help of the command)
9. Check-in.

Then you'll have the relationship between both branch and the content you want in both.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said that you don't care about history but would you take it if you could get it for free?  The best thing to do here is an upgrade, or an import of a Team Project Collection.  If you take backups of all of your 2005 databases and restore them on the TFS 2010 data tier you can then run "[tfsconfig.exe import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407080.aspx)".  This is the most supported way to get your data from one server to the other.

Comment: will that work if we are moving the computes from one domain to another with a complete new setup of user accounts?

Comment: Yep, TFS is built to handle that.  The worst case scenario is that your new identities don't line up properly with your old identities.  In that case, you still have all of your historical metadata and can tell who caused those changes.  Here is a post about solving the identity problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vasu_sankaran/archive/2010/05/11/guidance-for-upgrading-to-tfs-2010-along-with-domain-move.aspx.  Here is another entry on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx#MoveAccounts

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This is a common misconception when working with TFS.  The integration platform should not be used to replace upgrade.  Upgrade is put through rigorous testing and is much more likely to work.  The TFS integration platform is useful but it comes with a tax that will not go away until the integrations are stopped.  With upgrade, you'll pay a bit of tax with taking the server offline and upgrading it, but once it is done there is no more tax to pay.